# Swing Model View Presenter (MVP) example

Tags: java, swing

I've been reading up on the MVP pattern, and have been unable to find a Java Swing code example. Does anyone know an opensource project that uses this pattern or where I could find such an example? (I'm not looking to use a framework to help implement the pattern, just an example.)

Comment: Entered `Swing Model View Presenter (MVP) example` to the google. 4-th link is: http://code.google.com/p/pennychecker-presenter/downloads/detail?name=swing-mvp-example.zip

Comment: This question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519725/applying-the-mvp-pattern-to-jdialogs

Answer (score 3):

Actually, from a certain point of view, all of Swing can be seen as a MVP model(
It really is turtles all the way down).

```
Models:
  ListModel, TableModel, etc.
Presenter:
  All Swing widgets, such as JLabel, JTable, JPanel etc.
View:
  ListUI, PanelUI, LayoutManagers, etc.
```

I've written several systems using MVP with Swing, JSP, and GWT, and have been extremely happy with the results each time.

Answer (score 0):

After installing JDK (1.6 in this case) you can find all kind of demos in

> "JDK instalation path"\jdk1.6.0_29\demo

and particularly in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\demo\jfc

you will find 
SwingApplet, SwingSet2 and SwingSet3 demos that allow to even see the code for the demo you choose to give it a try.